# Automated testing tool for java post development

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, log4j

I have an existing java application which is developed in Netbeans this is my first major development project so i didn't think about the use of log4j & junit in first place(A good lesson learnt). since now i am at the end of the project i miss these two . is there is any tool or jar which can create automated testing & logging with minimum effort ? I guess Adding log4j is easy but what about junit ?

Comment: junit is just a framework for running test. You still have to write the tests.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis is there is any to write automated test ?

Comment: A unit test tests different units (single methods or classes). Unless your units are exactly the same, you can't automate tests to compare expected results against actual results.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to say that you cannot use Junit after you have created a project. It means that you are not making use of test driven development, but there is no reason why that is an issue once you have already created your project.
I would recommend the netbeans tutorial on exactly how to do that:
https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/junit-intro.html